# How can I store old emails outside of my IMAP account?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, imap

I have a bunch of old mails in my inbox. I access it via Microsoft Outlook using the IMAP protocol. My server space is running out :(.

I want to keep the old mails available and searchable and easy to backup. Can I archive them somehow? Where are they stored then?

I would prefer not having to move away from Outlook, if at all possible. If another email client works better, I can consider using it but I would rather not.

Comment: Where is space running out? On the mail server, or on your local machine?

Comment: On the mail server.

Comment: I used Outlook with POP3 for years, and created a new PST as an archive folder and simply moved old e-mails into them. I did try Outlook's own archiving function, but it didn't work quite as I wanted. It won't work quite the same with IMAP, but you should be able to use a similar technique.

Comment: You can archive them locally Outlook offers to do this for you.  But if the local .PST is lost then so are the emails contained within it.  Why can't you just expand the storage of the server?

Comment: @Ramhound I'm cheap :D

Answer (score 3):

You didn't say, which version of Outlook you are using, but principle is same in all versions.

You can archive your email, and it will move outside your inbox and IMAP account.

Depending on the version of Outlook you are using, you would do something like this:

- Click File > Info > Cleanup Tools
- Select Archive from dropdown box
- Select the date, older from which items will be archived.

PST file with Archived items will be created inside a path like this

`drive:\Users\<Your LogInName>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Outlook\archive.pst`

All emails older from the date you selected will be moved in folders inside Archive, and outside your inbox and server storage.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2720581#method3

Comment: Please summarize the steps of your source

Comment: And that gets you over 1k, congrats.